# Error de clave primaria en Java

Tags: java, orm

Tengo la siguiente clase en la cual quiero que la variable ref se asigne automaticamente con *jdo*.

Parece que la clase en su mayoria esta bien y que el metodo para guardar cada libro es el que está fallando ya que cuando hago `.flush()`, sí, me los guarda, pero de forma brusca y permanente, sin embargo, cuando lo que hago es un `.commit` me da error en la clave primaria parece ser.

```
@Entity 
public class libro  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*
    @Entity: Define que esta clase se utilizará como entidad en nuestra base de datos.
    @Id: Identifica que el campo que estamos definiendo a continuación será el campo identificador dentro de la entidad.
    @GeneratedValue: Especifica que el sistema generará de forma automática el identificador. 
    */
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int ref;

    private String nombre;
    private String autor;
    private String genero;
    private boolean leido;
    private int puntuacion;
    private String comentarios;
    public static int referencia = 0; 

    public libro() {
    }

    // Constructor 
    public libro(String nombre, String autor, String genero, boolean leido, int puntuacion, String comentarios) {
        // Referencia ++;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.leido = leido;
        this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
        this.comentarios = comentarios;
        // ref=referencia;
        // Impido que la puntuación sea mayor de 10 o menor de 0
        if (puntuacion>10){
            this.puntuacion=10;
        }
        else{
            this.puntuacion=puntuacion;
        }
        if (puntuacion<0){
        this.puntuacion=10;
        }
        else{
            this.puntuacion=puntuacion;
        }
    }

    public int getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(int ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public boolean isLeido() {
        return leido;
    }

    public void setLeido(boolean leido) {
        this.leido = leido;
    }

    public int getPuntuacion() {
        return puntuacion;
    }

    public void setPuntuacion(int puntuacion) {
        this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
    }

    public String getComentarios() {
        return comentarios;
    }

    public void setComentarios(String comentarios) {
        this.comentarios = comentarios;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
     return String.format("(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        this.nombre,
        this.autor,
        this.genero,
        this.leido,
        this.puntuacion,
        this.comentarios);
    }
}
```

Ahora en el `main` tengo para introducir de la siguiente manera:

```
private void insertarlibro(EntityManager entityManager) {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    // Para crear un libro: nombre, autor, genero, leido o no(true,false) nota(int) y descripcion
    entityManager.persist(new libro("The magicean","amazon prime","fantasia",false,7,"se hizo una serie del libro"));
    entityManager.persist(new libro("la rueda del tiempo","James Oliver Rigney, Jr","fantasia",true,8,"una saga de actualmente 20
    libros"));
    entityManager.persist(new libro("charlie y la fabrica de chocolate","Roald Dahl","fantasia",true,20,"tercer libro de la
    saga"));
    entityManager.persist(new libro("el hombre en el castillo","Philip K. Dick","ciencia ficcion",true,6,"se hizo una serie
    en amazon"));
    entityManager.persist(new libro("sueñan los androides con ovejas electricas","Philip K. Dick","ciencia ficcion",false,2,"en la que se
    baso blade runner"));
    entityManager.persist(new libro("outfan","cels piñol","rol",true,1,"juego de rol de humor espacial"));
    // entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Cuando lo cargo con `this.insertarlibro(entityManager);` me salta:

> Failed to commit transaction: Attempt to reuse an existing primary key value (pspt5.libro:1) (error 613)
>   at com.objectdb.jpa.EMImpl.commit(EMImpl.java:289)

Entiendo que es un fallo de *clave primaria* o algo pero supongo que me lo arregla o el *constructor* o el *override* que no sé como configurarlo adecuadamente.

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Answer (score 0):

La solucion principal fue borrar el archivo `.dbo`.

Comment: ¿Eso significa que también hubo una solucion que no fue principal? Si es así puedes [editar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/329330/edit) agregando los detalles necesarios para que sea completa.